# Reset seleted children for a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that takes two parameter. first is parentelement and second is excluded elements. the function should reset all children except the list of elements send in second argument to be excluded and should not reset. I have got some success using selectors as per below method. Now I have two queries

```
function resetdetaildata(parentselector, elem) {  
        var $self = $(parentselector);
        if(elem == '')
        {
            $($self).children().find('input').val("");
            $($self).children().find('select').each(function () {
                $(this).find('option:gt(0)').remove();
                $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert(parentselector);
            $($self).children('input:not(' + elem + ')').find('input').val("");
            $($self).children('select:not(' + elem + ')').find('select').each(function () {
                $(this).find('option:gt(0)').remove();
                $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
            });
        }
    }
```

Currently I am calling this method like this

```
resetdetaildata('#Parent', '.clsmaterial');
```

- How to change arguments from selectors to elements.
- Making second   argument as array and calling it from code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder function calling is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do the `find` call after doing the `children` call. `find` looks **within** the elements in the set, but `input` elements can never be within other `input` elements, and `select` elements can never be within other `select` elements.

Separately, you never want to use `$()` on a jQuery set (`$($self)`).

I'd probably find all the `input`s and `selects` first, then use [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) if `elem` is truthy to remove the ones I don't want to match.

```
function resetdetaildata(parentselector, elem) {  
    var $self = $(parentselector);
    // Find all inputs and selects
    var $inputs = $self.find('input');
    var $selects = $self.find('select');
    if (elem)
    {
        // We're filtering, so do that
        $inputs = $inputs.not(elem);
        $selects = $selets.not(elem);
    }
    $inputs.val("");
    $selects.each(function () {
        $(this).find('option:gt(0)').remove();
        $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
    });
}
```

---

Side note: You can make the code removing all but the first `option` in the `select`s a bit simpler by using the DOM directly:

```
function resetdetaildata(parentselector, elem) {  
    var $self = $(parentselector);
    // Find all inputs and selects
    var $inputs = $self.find('input');
    var $selects = $self.find('select');
    if (elem)
    {
        // We're filtering, so do that
        $inputs = $inputs.not(elem);
        $selects = $selets.not(elem);
    }
    $inputs.val("");
    $selects.each(function () {
        this.options.length = 1; // <== Removes all options except the first
        this.selectedIndex = 0;  // <== Selects the first option
    });
}
```

Comment: How i will be calling this method specially if I want to send multiple excludes in second element. One option come in mind is to decorate all of them with same class is there any other way without class decoration

Comment: @Zia - The above is happy if you pass in any valid selector string. So for instance, if you wanted not to reset `.foo` elements and `.bar` elements, providing the string `".foo, .bar"` would exclude them. See [`not`](https://api.jquery.com/not/).